# How to freeze a python library into a linux program?

Tags: python, linux, bash

We can surely freeze a python script into stand-alone binaries in a lots of ways. I personally like `pyinstaller` and `freeze.py` the best. But, as of them, the finally binaries need to be executed as

```
$ ./hello-world
```

if I've converted a file named `hello-world.py`. I want a python script to turn into a program so as when I type

```
$ hello-world
```

It runs the python script. I really have no idea how this can be done and I can't find a suitable answer to this question.

EDIT : I want to make a binary program of a whole library. How to use things like `pyinstaller` in that case?

Comment: The problem you are experiencing is not a python problem but a security feature of most shells. You can not call an executable on the current directory without a path. This prevents for example someone to place a malicious program called `ls` in some directory which then would be called when you list that directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to have the script in your `$PATH`

```
$ ls
script.py
$ PATH=$PATH:`pwd`

$ script.py
# script runs without ./
```

a much better alternative would be to move the script in a folder already in path, viz `/usr/local/bin/`

```
$ mv script.py /usr/local/bin

$ script.py
# script runs without ./
```

Comment: Adding the local directory to `$PATH` did the job. I wonder why the current directory is not included in `$PATH` already?

Comment: `$PATH` doesn't get automatically updated to include present directory. look over to this project for such things https://github.com/kennethreitz/autoenv

Comment: So, this is the case for a single python script. What about a whole project which gets installed by pip or something? How to modify it's `setup.py` so that it generates the binary and puts it on of the `$PATH` directories?

Comment: @HimanshuMishra `setuptools` has builtin support for installing console scripts. Why don't you read the docs? https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Comment: @4ae1e1 Thanks a lot.